# /bin/bash: line 1: simg2img: command not found

Tags: command-line, bash

when I run a command `simg2img` I get the following error:

```
/bin/bash: line 1: simg2img: command not found.
```

MakeFile Snippet:

```
if [ true = true ]; then \
        simg2img out/target/product/evk_6sl/system_sparse.img out/target/product/evk_6sl/system.img; \
fi
```

If I check `simg2img` is obtained in the path

```
 /out/host/linux-x86/bin/simg2img
```

And this path is also in `$PATH`.

Running `sim2img --help` prints:

```
~/Android_Source$ simg2img --help
Usage: simg2img <sparse_image_files> <raw_image_file>

~/Android_Source/out/host/linux-x86/bin$ id 
uid=1000(accord) gid=1000(accord) groups=1000(accord),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)

~/Android_Source/out/host/linux-x86/bin$ ls -lZ simg2img

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root ? 282920 Dec  9 17:36 simg2img

~/Android_Source/out/host/linux-x86/bin$ echo $PATH

/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin:/home/accord/Android_Source/out/host/linux-x86/bin:/home/accord/Android_Source/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin:/home/accord/Android_Source/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/:/home/accord/Android_Source/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin:/home/accord/Android_Source/development/scripts:/home/accord/Android_Source/prebuilts/devtools/tools:/home/accord/Android_Source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64:/home/accord/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/accord/Android_Source/out/host/linux-x86/bin

~/Android_Source/out/host/linux-x86/bin$ which simg2img

/home/accord/Android_Source/out/host/linux-x86/bin/simg2img
```

Why am I still getting the `simg2img command not found` error?

Comment: Add output of `id`, `ls -lZ /out/host/linux-x86/bin/simg2img` and `echo $PATH`to your question.

Comment: The error means the command is not in your `$PATH`. Add the information Cyrus asked for and we should be able to tell you why. Also tell us exactly how you are running the script.

Comment: If possible share the entire line 1 of the script.

Answer (score 0):

`/bin/bash: line 1: simg2img: command not found.` means that the first line in `simg2img` contains a command that cannot be found.

You could try inspecting this line(`nano /out/host/linux-x86/bin/simg2img`); it might just be a dependency.